# ¿Por que mi formulario no guarda datos en la base de datos PhpMyAdmin usando PHP?

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, tablas, cuenta-usuario, adminlte

Muy buenas a todos, estoy haciendo un formulario para registrar usuarios a partir de la plantilla Adminlte 3.1.0. La cuestión es que en **usuarios.php** yo tengo una tabla donde voy a administrar todos los usuarios a los que les voy a aplicar el CRUD. Mientras que en mi clase **usuarios.modelo.php** tengo todo lo que es funciones, variables, alertas, etc., y es en esta misma donde tengo mi código para crear un usuario. Por algún motivo y pese a que tengo una clase llamada **conexion.php** donde me conecto a mi base de datos, nunca se llega a almacenar los datos que ingreso a mi base. Ya rehíce el código y aun sigo teniendo este problema, de verdad estaría agradecido si me pudieran guiar

[image: Imagen de la base de datos]

Los códigos son estos, los separe para no perderme:

usuarios.php:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h1>Administrar Usuarios</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Administrar usuarios</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </section>
    
  <section class="content">

    <!-- CAJA POR DEFAULT -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">

        <!-- BOTON AGREGAR USUARIO -->
        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarUsuario">
          Agregar usuario
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- CUERPO DE LA CAJA -->
      <div class="card-body table-responsive">

        <!-- TABLA DE REGISTRO -->
        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-dark table-striped table-hover tablas">
          <!-- PRIMERA FILA -->
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10px">#</th>
            <th>Tipo de usuario</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th>Perfil</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Ultimo login</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <!-- SEGUNDA FILA -->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Administrador</td>
              <td>admin</td>
              <td> <img src="vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonimo.png" class="rounded-circle" width="56px"></td>
              <td>Administrador</td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-group-xs">Activo</button></td>
              <td>2021-12-11 12:05:40</td>
              <!-- BOTONERA PARA MODIFICAR -->
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></i></button>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <!-- TERCERA FILA -->
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Vendedor</td>
            <td>Vend</td>
            <td> <img src="vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonimo.png" class="rounded-circle" width="56px"></td>
            <td>Vendedor</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-group-xs">Desactivado</button></td>
            <td>2021-12-11 12:05:40</td>
            <!-- BOTONERA PARA MODIFICAR -->
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></i></button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>


        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!--=======================================================
                   VENTANA AGREGAR USUARIO
  ======================================================-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregarUsuario" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content" style="background:#343a40">

      <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- CABEZA DEL MODAL -->
        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#007bff; color:white">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar usuario</h4>
          
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- CAJA DEL MODAL USUARIO -->
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">

                <!-- FORMULARIO -->
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- INGRESO NOMBRE DEL USUARIO -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoNombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- CAJA DEL MODAL USUARIO -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- INGRESO TIPO DE USUARIO -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoUsuario" placeholder="Ingresar usuario" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- CAJA DEL MODAL CONTRA -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- INGRESO TIPO DE CONTRASENA -->
                <input type="pasword" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPassword" placeholder="Ingresar contrasena" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR EL PERFIL -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- SELECCIONO TIPO DE PERFIL -->
                <select class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPerfil">
                  <option value="">Seleccionar perfil</option>
                  <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
                  <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                  <option value="Productor">Productor</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR FOTO -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="panel">Subir foto</div>
              <input type="file" class="nuevaFoto" name="nuevaFoto">
              <p class="help-block">Peso maximo de la foto 2 MB</p>
              <img src="vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonimo.png" class="img-thumbnail-circle previsualizar" width="100px">
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

<!--=======================================================
                   PIE DE MODAL
  ======================================================-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:black">Cerrar</button>
        </div>

        <?php
        $crearUsuario = new ControladorUsuarios();
        $crearUsuario-> ctrCrearUsuario();

        ?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

usuarios.controlador.php

```
    <?php
class ControladorUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    INGRESO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])){

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

                if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["ingPassword"]){

                    $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "activo";

                    echo '<script>

                        window.location = "inicio";

                    </script>';

                }else{
                    echo '<script>

                    Swal.fire({
                      icon: "error",
                      title: "<strong>ERROR</strong>",
                      text: "La contrasena o usuario ingresado no es valido. Por favor verifique y vuelva a intentar",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                      
                    }).then((result) => {
                      if (result.value) {
                        window.location = "ingreso";
                      }
                    })
                </script>';
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    /*=============================================
    REGISTRAR USUARIO
    =============================================*/
    static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){

                /*=============================================
                VALIDAR IMAGEN
                =============================================*/

                $ruta = "";

                if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"])){

                    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                    $nuevoAncho = 500;
                    $nuevoAlto = 500;

                    /*=============================================
                    CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO DONDE VAMOS A GUARDAR LA FOTO DEL USUARIO
                    =============================================*/

                    $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"];

                    mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    /*=============================================
                    DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP
                    =============================================*/

                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){

                        /*=============================================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO COMO JPG
                        =============================================*/

                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";

                        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                        

                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                        imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);
                    }

                    if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/png"){

                        /*=============================================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO COMO PNG
                        =============================================*/

                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".png";

                        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                     

                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagepng($destino, $ruta);

                    }
                }

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $encriptar = crypt($_POST["nuevoPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');

                $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                               "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                               "password" => $encriptar,
                               "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"],
                               "foto"=>$ruta);
                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);
            
                if($respuesta == "ok"){

                    echo '<script>

                    Swal.fire({
                          icon: "success",
                          title: "<strong>EXITO!</strong>",
                          text: "El usuario se ha creado satisfactoriamente",
                          showConfirmButton: true,
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                      
                    }).then((result) => {
                      if (result.value) {
                        window.location = "usuarios";
                      }
                    })
                </script>';
                }   
            }else{

                echo '<script>

                    Swal.fire({
                      icon: "error",
                      title: "<strong>ERROR</strong>",
                      text: "El nombre no puede llevar caracteres especiales",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                      
                    }).then((result) => {
                      if (result.value) {
                        window.location = "usuarios";
                      }
                    })

                </script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usuarios.modelo.php

```
    <?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR USUARIOS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();
        $stmt -> close();
        $stmt = null;
    }

    /*=============================================
    REGISTRO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/
    static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(id, nombre, usuario, password, perfil, foto) VALUES 
            (1, :nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil, :foto)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":foto", $datos["foto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";    
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

conexion.php

```
    <?php

class Conexion{

    static public function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pos", "root", "");

        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link; 
    }
}
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin es una herramienta, el motor de base de datos que utilizas ha de ser o MySQL o MariaDB. Además, agrega etiquetas relevantes a tu pregunta (en este caso son `php` y `mysql` (o `mariadb`)). ¿Da algún mensaje de error? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Efectivamente, uso MySQL. Tampoco me da error, es más, cuando lo mencionaste pensé que mi base no la tenia correctamente declarada en mis archivos, pero comprobé que agregando usuarios desde la base, al abrir el login si me los acepta y me deja navegar. Pero desde la página no me los agrega.

Comment: Agrega los atributos necesarios para que PDO muestre los errores:

$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);